# Can I buy a select seat at the check-in counter?

Tags: air-travel, europe, budget, seating, norwegian-air-shuttle

I will fly with Norwegian from BUD to CPH in February. I have a LowFare ticket so the seat selection is €12. I know that if I don’t reserve a seat in advance, I will get one random upon check-in which is possible online 24h before departure.
My question is: if I don’t want the randomly assigned seat after check-in, can I still buy another seat that time for a fee?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will. All of this is on Norwegian's website, [here](https://www.norwegian.com/us/travel-info/on-board/seat-reservation/). To quote:

"If you’ve purchased a LowFare ticket and you don’t really mind where you sit, then not to worry – we’ll automatically assign a seat for you on the day of departure. There will be a charge to change your seat if you’re unhappy with the one we’ve assigned to you when you arrive at the airport."

Note that the price will be a few dollars more:
"LowFare: 12 - 26 USD (online)  30 USD (airport) per person, per leg"

Comment: Ohh shame on me not reading norwegian’s site properly... Thank you for the info and link!

Comment: @zdtorok But assuming there are seats available.  If they sold out, of course, you won't be able to upgrade.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Yes, good point